# Right way to exclude R.java from javadoc using gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, javadoc

I'm generating javadoc for my Android project with this gradle task:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
        description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
        source = variant.javaCompile.source
        classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files, project.android.getBootClasspath())
        exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
        exclude '**/R.java'
        options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/");
        options.linksOffline("http://d.android.com/reference","${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference");
        options {
            failOnError false
        }
        destinationDir = file("${project.projectDir}/javadoc")
    }
}
```

It excludes `R.java`, so i don't get R.html in output dir.
However, i'm getting very annoying errors `cannot find symbol class R` in the process of generating doc for my usual java classes, in the line `import com.mypackagename.R`. I use common android things like `R.string.string_res`, so i can't remove this import.
Is there a proper way to include symbol `R` to index, but not include it to a javadoc, or, at least, simply to supress this error?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add next two lines to your code:

```
classpath += files("build/generated/source/r/${variant.flavorName}/release")
classpath += files("build/generated/source/buildConfig/${variant.flavorName}/release")
```

But in this case your task should depend on one of the tasks which generates R classes.